# Incremental updates for Mobile App API

Tags: api, mobile, architecture

I am designing an GraphQL Api which will be consumed via an Mobile App. Mobile App does an initial sync which fetches all data from the server (via GraphQl) but it will need to refresh his data in regular intervals. Instead of fetching all data again (which does take a lot of time) I would like to fetch all updated or newly created records.
For now I am thinking about approach of sending some header like "FETCH_RECORDS_SINCE" and based on it to return only data which are updated/created after that timestamp. Each db table has created and updated columns so I can achieve something like that.

I would like to ask community if someone has similar problem and come up with different solution (or same as my proposal), also I am looking for some other ideas on how to solve this requirement, probably there is some other ideas that I could not think of.

P.S. I am using GraphQl but design should not be much different from REST Api, so if someone had experience solving similar problem with REST is also welcomed :)

Any idea is welcome!

Comment: You can think of some push mechanisms like through web sockets, HTTP/2..this will be more real time behaviour for the app...GCM and APN also provides support for push mechanisms

Comment: Thanks for reply @saurav That is an option, but in my case wont work that great since app in some cases will be offline

Comment: Hi @MarkoTrajkov how did you finally implement this? Thanks.

Comment: for now (in GrapQL I am using/implemented filters to filter records which has been modified since last sync, something like this:
`my_objects(filterBy: { modified: { startDatetime: "2000-01-01T00:00:00+00:00" } }`